# Order of an automorphism of a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, gr.group-theory

Let G be a finite group of order n.  Must every automorphism of G have order less than n?

(David Speyer: I got this question from you long ago, but I don't know whether you knew the answer.  I stil don't!)

Comment: Nope, I didn't know the answer. But now I do!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes every automorphism has order bounded by |G|-1, provided G is not the trivial group. A reference is
M V Horoševskiĭ 1974 Math. USSR Sb. 22 584-594
which can be found at
http://www.iop.org/EJ/abstract/0025-5734/22/4/A08/

It is even shown that the upper bound is reached only for elementary abelian groups.

Comment: Great!  Now if only I could read Russian... :)

Comment: The link is to an english translation ;)

Comment: So it is!  (I googled for a freely available copy and found one in Russian...)

Comment: This was fun to read--very clever, entirely elementary arguments--thanks again.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: This is currently Problem 11681 in AMM Vol. 119, No. 10 (December 2012).

Comment: The proof is given in the book of Isaacs on Finite Group Theory (p.70).